# Atualizar planilha XLS sem sobrescrever os dados usando R

Tags: r

Eu preciso adicionar novas informações a planilha xls, mas essa já tem informações que foram anteriormente inseridas. Eu preciso que esses dados estejam numa mesma sheet.

Existe a possibilidade de atualizar uma planilha sem sobrescrever os dados que já existem?

Estou usando o write.xls da forma mais simples possível:

```
write.xlsx(obj, path, sheetName="Dados")
```

Eu tentei usar o append, mas ele sempre sobrescreve ou cria os dados numa sheet diferente. Tem uma outra forma de fazer isso?

Comment: Você tem que, obrigatoriamente, salvar em .xlsx? É muito mais prático trabalhar com outputs em .csv, em R.

Comment: Vou testar, @Molx . Não preciso usar xlsx obrigatoriamente.

Comment: O problema é que nem todos os meus dados tem as mesmas quantidades de linhas. Por exemplo, eu tenho um conjunto com 3 linhas. Depois preciso adicionar outro conjunto com 4 linhas.. a unica coisa em comum é que todos tem informações (x,y). Mas ai quando tento usar .csv ele reclama dizendo que a quantidade de informações não é compatível.

Comment: Você pode fazer o append usando .csv independente do número de linhas. Talvez o problema esteja na tentativa de escrever headers ou row numbers, por isso o erro. Talvez seja uma boa ideia considerar esse tipo de abordagem em uma próxima vez, já que este problema está resolvido.

Comment: Vou testar, mesmo que a outra tenha dado certo, @Molx :)

Comment: @Molx deu super certo mesmo e é muito mais simples! :) Muito obrigada por suas boas ideias.

Comment: Ótimo! O R não gosta de xls, então é bom evitar, especialmente como output. Arquivos de texto são mais simples e fáceis de trabalhar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se os seus dados não forem muito grandes, eu criaria uma função assim:

```
write.xlsx2 <- function(obj, path, sheetName){
  dados <- read.xlsx(path = path, sheetName = sheetName)
  dados <- rbind(dados, obj)
  write.xlsx(dados, path = path, sheetName = sheetName)   
}
```

- Leio os dados que já estão no excel p/ o R
- Dentro do R, empilho os dois
- escrevo tudo de novo

Não é a forma mais segura, mas deve funcionar na maioria dos casos.

Comment: Legal! Gostei de ideia! É funcional :)